# Why the @OneToMany annotation is not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

**My Question:**

I want to store STORE_ID and BOOK_ID In INVENTORY table but Why not the STORE_ID store in Inventory table? I am new new in JPA please suggest me what i do for store STORE_ID  in INVENTORY table.

**1.Book**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="book_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private Date publishedOn;
    private Double price;
    private int version = -1;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="book")
    Inventory inventoryRecords = new Inventory();
```

**2.Inventory**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="inventory")
public class Inventory implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name="INVENTORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private Book book;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="STORE_ID")
    private Set<Store> stores = new HashSet<Store>();

    private Integer quantity;
```

**3.Store**

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="store")
public class Store implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="STORE_ID")    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="NickName")
    private String nickName;
```

**4.In Main**

```
Book b = new Book();
        b.setTitle("abc");
        b.setIsbn("abc");

    Inventory i = new Inventory();     
        i.setBook(b); 
        b.setInventoryRecords(i); 

    Store s = new Store();

        s.setNickName("yyynn6");
        i.getStores().add(s);
        entitymanager.persist(b);

    OUTPUT=
    Hibernate: insert into book (isbn, price, publishedOn, title, version) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into inventory (book_id, quantity) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into store (NickName) values (?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed it up on DB level. If store has many books in it, I would get rid of Inventory entity and do this:

On Store:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="store", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Book> books= new HashSet<Book>();
```

On Book:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "STORE_ID")
private Store store;
```

Do you really need the Inventory table?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but your suggestion is not working in my case , I have three class Book,Inventory And Store. I persiste only Book so that time want store all data with respective table + Inventory table with Book_ID and Store_ID. I have try @manyToOne in Store Class with mapped by but it not working

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen a wrong column for the relationship; you annotated the `Id` of `Store` entity to be the join column, you also haven't specified the reverse relation in other side, I prefer to provide a `INVENTORY_ID` column inside Store:

In Store:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="INVENTORY_ID")
private Inventory inventory;
```

and in Inventory :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="inventory",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="INVENTORY_ID")
private Set<Store> inventories=new HashSet<Store>();
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but your suggestion is not working in my case , I have three class Book,Inventory And Store. I persiste only Book so that time want store all data with respective table + Inventory table with Book_ID and Store_ID. I have try @manyToOne in Store Class with mappedBy=stores   but it not working.

Comment: You are welcome but as you asked _Why the @OneToMany annotation is not working?_ that's why I explained only one-to-many part of it, of course you have to correct the one-to-one relationship between `Book` and `Inventory` entities and bring the book inside Inventory too

Answer (score 0):

Prashant u are doing wrong mapping thats why ur query not fired correctly and data not inserting in Inventory Table.So please Correct ur mapping.